# spark-submit unable to connect

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

After running the command

```
spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --proxy-user yarn --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --driver-memory 4g --executor-memory 2g --executor-cores 1 --queue default ./examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.3.0.jar 10000
```

I get this in the output and it keeps on retrying. Where am I going wrong? Am I missing some configuration?

I have created a new user for yarn and running that user.

```
WARN  Utils:66 - Your hostname, ukaleem-HP-EliteBook-850-G3 resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 10.XX.XX.XX instead (on interface enp0s31f6)
2018-06-14 16:50:41 WARN  Utils:66 - Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
Warning: Local jar /home/yarn/Documents/Scala-Examples/./examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.3.0.jar does not exist, skipping.
2018-06-14 16:50:42 INFO  RMProxy:98 - Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
2018-06-14 16:50:44 INFO  Client:871 - Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
```

And in the end, it gives the exception

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Call From ukaleem-HP-EliteBook-850-G3/127.0.1.1 to 0.0.0.0:8032 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor4.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:792)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:732)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy8.getClusterMetrics(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.client.ApplicationClientProtocolPBClientImpl.getClusterMetrics(ApplicationClientProtocolPBClientImpl.java:206)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.getClusterMetrics(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl.getYarnClusterMetrics(YarnClientImpl.java:487)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$submitApplication$1.apply(Client.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$submitApplication$1.apply(Client.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.logInfo(Logging.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.logInfo(Client.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.submitApplication(Client.scala:154)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1146)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.YarnClusterApplication.start(Client.scala:1518)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:879)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$1.run(SparkSubmit.scala:179)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$1.run(SparkSubmit.scala:177)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:177)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:227)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:531)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:495)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:614)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:712)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2900(Client.java:375)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1528)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1451)
    ... 28 more
2018-06-14 17:10:53 INFO  ShutdownHookManager:54 - Shutdown hook called
2018-06-14 17:10:53 INFO  ShutdownHookManager:54 - Deleting directory /tmp/spark-5bddb7f3-165f-451c-8ab4-bb7729f4237c
```

**EDIT :** After adding config files to my spark/conf dir, I get this error now.

The files I added are

*core-site.xml

dfs.hosts

masters

slaves

yarn-site.xml*

And some more. What I understand is that I only need yarn-site.xml to tell spark the location of the yarn cluster. (ids, address, hostname etc).

All this time I had been thinking that even we want to submit a job on Yarn these config need to go in /etc/Hadoop dir not in Spark/conf. Whats the purpose of installing hadoop then (other than communicating)?
And following this question. If the config need to go in spark/conf then **HADOOP_CONF_DIR** & **YARN_CONF_DIR** should point to etc/hadoop dir or spark/conf?

```
    INFO client.ConfiguredRMFailoverProxyProvider: Failing over to rm2
18/06/19 11:04:50 INFO retry.RetryInvocationHandler: Exception while invoking getClusterMetrics of class ApplicationClientProtocolPBClientImpl over rm2 after 1 fail over attempts. Trying to fail over after sleeping for 38176ms.
java.net.ConnectException: Call From ukaleem-HP-EliteBook-850-G3/127.0.1.1 to svc-hadoop-mgnt-pre-c2-01.jamba.net:8032 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:792)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:732)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13.getClusterMetrics(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.client.ApplicationClientProtocolPBClientImpl.getClusterMetrics(ApplicationClientProtocolPBClientImpl.java:206)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.getClusterMetrics(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl.getYarnClusterMetrics(YarnClientImpl.java:487)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$submitApplication$1.apply(Client.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$submitApplication$1.apply(Client.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.logInfo(Logging.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.logInfo(Client.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.submitApplication(Client.scala:154)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1146)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.YarnClusterApplication.start(Client.scala:1518)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:879)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$1.run(SparkSubmit.scala:179)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$1.run(SparkSubmit.scala:177)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:177)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:227)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:531)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:495)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:614)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:712)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2900(Client.java:375)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1528)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1451)
    ... 29 more
```

Comment: You need to **remove** 127.0.1.1 from all hosts files in the cluster... Hostnames should resolve to external addresses, not local ones

Comment: Also, `ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032`... This needs to be an actual IP address in the yarn-site.xml

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a fully distributed yarn cluster: your spark-submit script is unable to find the configuration for the yarn resourcemanager (basically the yarn master node). Ensure you have `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` properly set in your environment, and that it points to your cluster's configuration. Specifically your `yarn-site.xml`.

## Edit: more detail

The hadoop package comes with both *server* and *client* software. The *server* software would be the many daemons that run that make up the cluster. If your workstation is acting as a *client* (using that term loosely, not fully related to sparks `--deploy-mode`), then the hadoop *client* software must know the network locations of the *server* daemons running in the cluster. If your `yarn-site.xml` is empty, then it is pulling it's default values from [`yarn-defauls.xml`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml) (which is hard-coded, I believe).

Assuming your cluster is not running in HA mode, and is a mostly default configuration, then your workstation's `yarn-site.xml` should contain at least an entry like the following:

```
<property>
  <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
  <value>rm-host.yourdomain.com</value>
</property>
```

Obviously, replace the hostname with the hostname where your actual resource manager is running. Of course, any spark interaction with HDFS will require a properly configured `hdfs-site.xml`, etc.

Some cluster managing software will have something like "generate client configs" (thinking of my cloudera experience specifically), which will give you a `.tar.gz` with all of the config files correctly populated to access the cluster from an external workstation.

Further recommendations:
If you plan to do spark on yarn a lot in this cluster, spark recommends making sure that you have the [external shuffle service](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html#configuring-the-external-shuffle-service) configured to launch with your yarn node managers. (Please bear in mind, this config directive would have to be present in the `yarn-site.xml` where yarn's node manager services are running, not on your workstation.

Comment: I already set the HADOOP_CONF_DIR. Have tried both HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/conf and HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop.
This is where yarn-site.xml is but  there nothing in it, just he default file. Do i need to put something in it?
.my colleague is able to run jobs on the yarn cluster.

Comment: Checked the Hadoop connection refused page it says
Make sure the destination address in the exception isn't 0.0.0.0 -this means that you haven't actually configured the client with the real address for that service, and instead it is picking up the server-side property telling it to listen on every port for connections.

So, I think I need to give some address in the configuration file because it's trying to connect to 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032.

Comment: Correct, your `yarn-site.xml` should contain the configuration options for your yarn cluster. Perhaps your colleague can share his `yarn-site.xml` file with you? Better yet, his entire `HADOOP_HOME`?

Comment: ok! I'm having some trouble understanding. 
Do these conf files that need to be set should be in spark/conf/ dir or etc/hadoop/ dir. 
There's nothing mentioned in Spark Documentation!

Comment: I'm unable to find any blog or tutorial or documentation to link spark with yarn. All I find is set the paths like
SPARK_HOME HADOOP_CONF_DIR in .profile to make it accessible. 
I also changed spark-evh.sh and updated HADOOP_CONF_DIR AND YARN_CONF_DIR to etc/hadoop.

Other tutorials are how to setup a yarn cluster which i dont need here.
Just want to submit a job on the yarn cluster.

Comment: I've added a bit more detail to the answer, perhaps that will help? It's a bit confusing because the *client* configs and *server* daemon configs are pulled from the same file. If you can get a `yarn-site.xml` from one of your cluster members, it will contain all of the *client* directives required to access the cluster remotely.

Comment: Yes, It helped a bit I've updated the quest. I know hadoop has 3 services, hdfs, mapreduce and yarn. But i dont think for runnig a job I need any. I dont need hadoop as a server or client on my machine to run the job. Just --deploy-mode as you mentioned. 

My colleague told me the config files need to goto spark/conf but Im confused whether to put these (yarn-site.xml and others) in spark/conf or hadoop. I still think it should be in Hadoop dir.

Comment: If spark were stand-alone, then you would not need the hadoop configuration files, but since you want to run spark on yarn, then spark-submit needs to know where on the network to find the yarn resource manager, and that is determined with a proper `yarn-site.xml` (located in `HADOOP_CONF_DIR`). Please read the third paragraph [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html). `--deploy-mode` is separate in that it controls where the *driver* portion of your job runs (in the cluster, or locally on your workstation).

Comment: I believe you are correct that the client software is unnecessary, because it's baked into the spark code, but you **do** still need a `yarn-site.xml` in your `HADOOP_CONF_DIR`.

Comment: Yes! you're right. But its very strange. "Ensure that HADOOP_CONF_DIR or YARN_CONF_DIR points to the directory which contains the (client side) configuration files for the Hadoop cluster" They havent mendioned which config files need to be changed and what. 

I changed yarn-site.xml and core-site.xml in etc/hadoop and now getting other errors.
My colleague told me his is working without changing anything to the hadoop folder he did everything in the spark/conf even added hadoop config files there.
I'm really confused because of this.  I think its should be in HADOOP_CONF_DIR.

Comment: for now I made spark master and slave locally and started working on the app. 
But any help regarding yarn would be of great use becaus e have to do that eventually.

Answer (score -2):

If you are running this on your local machine,

Update your `/etc/hosts` file, Enter 127.0.0.1 against your hostname.

Comment: Yes, im running it on my local machine. 
why change it to localhost ip?
its 127.0.1.1 right now.

edit: it gives the same error just changed 127.0.1.1 to 127.0.0.1

Comment: If you aren't attempting to use an existing yarn cluster, then I'd recommend running with `--master local[n]`, where `n` is the number of cores on your workstation.

Comment: I know, the local works but I have a yarn cluster that I want to run the job on.