# Steps to Run Spark with Yarn

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

What are the steps to run Spark on YARN

What I have done so far. Created a user yarn and Installed both Spark and Hadoop. Ran a spark job locally.
I need help with the configs specially with (client side) configuration files for the Hadoop cluster. Unable to figure out where to put them, link them and getting errors for a long time now.

Check this 
[spark-submit unable to connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50860764/spark-submit-unable-to-connect/50862784?noredirect=1#comment88828993_50862784)

Comment: How are you installing Spark/Hadoop? Using Hortonworks/Cloudera, or just doing it on your own? Do you already have a YARN cluster?

Comment: did you start hadoop/yarn before you started the submit action?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you're looking for.

[Running Spark on Yarn](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html)

I guess you know that Yarn provides the resources to run your jobs. So you have to define the master as YARN in your codes.  And then upload the data on hdfs to run the Spark Jobs. I am attaching the apache docs, where you can find the guidance.

Comment: Doesnt works! I have provided the link to another question I asked. If you check that I have tried a lot different things.

Comment: @Sam you need to become more explicit about what's not working. According to the other question, your networking is not configured correctly, which must be done prior to any Hadoop configuration

Answer (score 0):

STEP 1: Configure YARN properly(yarn-site.xml) with some online reference and then for sanity checking whether YARN is installed properly or not run the below command

> yarn jar /opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.3.jar wordcount /tmp/abhijeet/hadoop.in /tmp/abhijeet/out/out.1

If this is working fine then your good to go.

STEP 2: Install Spark with reference to some online content and do the sanity checking using the below command whether spark is installed properly or not

> opt/spark/bin/spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --master local[*] /opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.1.1.jar

If this is working fine, it means spark is installed properly.

STEP 3: Now, it's the time to run spark over yarn

Run the below given command

```
/opt/spark/bin/spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --executor-memory 2G --num-executors 2 /opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.1.1.jar
```

If this one is working fine then Congratulations!

NOTE: The above given path is local to my system and all the jars used comes with the default package of Hadoop and Spark.